# I am using Card Layout to switch between panels but when I try to make a specific panel appear after pressing a button nothing happens

Tags: java, cardlayout

I am trying to get it so that when the next button is pressed it goes to the Customer page, but when I click the button nothing happens.

This is my code 
   package javaapplication1;

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test extends javax.swing.JPanel implements  ActionListener{

JButton firstButton, lastButton, nextButton, previousButton;
JPanel cardPanel;
String cardNames[] = new String[3];
int cardCounter = 0;

public JPanel createContentPane (){

    JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

    buttonPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));

    previousButton = new JButton("<- Previous");
    previousButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(previousButton);
    buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());        

    firstButton = new JButton("First");
    firstButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(firstButton);
    buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

    lastButton =  new JButton("Last");
    lastButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(lastButton);
    buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

    nextButton = new JButton("Next ->");
    nextButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(nextButton);
    buttonPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));

    JPanel Shop = new JPanel();
    Shop panel1 = new Shop(); 
    Shop.add(panel1);

    JPanel Items = new JPanel();
    Items panel2 = new Items(); 
    Items.add(panel2); 

    JPanel Customers = new JPanel();
    Customers panel3 = new Customers(); 
    Customers.add(panel3); 

    cardPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout(150, 50));

    cardNames[0] = "Component.CENTER";
    cardNames[1] = "Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT";
    cardNames[2] = "Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT";

    cardPanel.add(Shop, cardNames[0]);
    cardPanel.add(Items, cardNames[1]);
    cardPanel.add(Customers, cardNames[2]);

    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    bottomPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    bottomPanel.add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    bottomPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    totalGUI.add(bottomPanel);
    return totalGUI;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    if(e.getSource() == nextButton)
    {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cardPanel.getLayout());

        cl.show(cardPanel, "Customers");
    }
    /*
    if(e.getSource() == firstButton)
    {
        cl.first(cardPanel);
        cardCounter = 0;
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == lastButton)
    {
        cl.last(cardPanel);
        cardCounter = 2;
    }
    else 
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == previousButton)
    {
        cl.previous(cardPanel);
        if(cardCounter > 0)
        {
            cardCounter--;
        }
        else
        {
            cardCounter = 2;
        }*/
    }


protected static void createAndShowGUI() {

    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");

    Test demo = new Test();
    frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Why is this the case? Am I missing something?
I am only new to using Cardlayout and don't know how it fully works

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html).

From [CardLayout.addLayoutComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#addLayoutComponent-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-):

> The object specified by `constraints` must be a string. The card layout stores this string as a key-value pair that can be used for random access to a particular card. By calling the `show` method, an application can display the component with the specified name.

In other words, the String you pass to CardLayout.show *must* be identical to one of the strings you provided as a constraint when adding a component to the CardLayout.

The constraints you are using are:

- "Component.CENTER"
- "Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT"
- "Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT"

None of these match what you are passing to CardLayout.show:

```
cl.show(cardPanel, "Customers");
```